# How to split an array in two parts (from start to x and from x to end) in C?

Tags: c, arrays, split

I've looked around but there are many different answers and C is confusing, so I'd rather ask for my specific question.

So let's say I have an array like this:

```
[ls, -l, SPLIT, wc, -w]
```

So I want to split this array into two different (char) arrays like this:

```
[ls, -l] [wc, -w]
```

Do I use `realloc` and `malloc`?

Comment: Do you want one of the arrays to be the original array? Then both. Otherwise if you want to keep the original array in its original state, then you need to allocate two new arrays, and for that you can use either function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would like to keep the original array, yes.

Comment: Your example isn't C. It is not clear what kind of array/arrays you are talking about. For example, are those comma parts of the strings, or are they pseudo code array element delimiters? Better provide a C example.

Comment: "*two different (char) arrays*" isn't it that you want two arrays of `char`-arrays? `"ls"` for example is a `char` array already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neet to `realloc`, but you will have to `malloc` twice. This is an exemple splitting in position 5 of a array of chars of size 10.

```
char * array = malloc (sizeof(char) * 10);
memcpy (array, data, sizeof(char) * 10);
char * split_part_1 = array;
size_t split_part_1_len = 5;
char * split_part_2 = malloc (sizeof(char) * (10 - 5));
memove (split_part_2, array + 5, sizeof(char) * 5);
size_t split_part_2_len = 5;
```

Use the arrays, now to free:

```
free (split_part_1);
free (split_part_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define separator ", SPLIT, "

int main(void) {
    char original[] = "ls, -l, SPLIT, wc, -w";
    char part1[sizeof original], part2[sizeof original];//or allocate by malloc
    char *d = part1, *s = original;
    char *p = strstr(s, separator);

    while(s < p){
        *d++ = *s++;
    }
    *d = 0;
    strcpy(part2, p + strlen(separator));
    printf("[%s] [%s]\n", part1, part2);
    return 0;
}
```